# Ion input type number is allowing dots in an ionic form

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic app. In one of the form field i have to input mobile number, below is the code i written

```
<ion-label position="floating">Mobile No.</ion-label>

<ion-input type="number" inputMode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" ></ion-input>
```

iam getting numerical keypad and allowing numbers but it allowing dot (.) also. I want to input only numbers.

please help me on this

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want a phone number, you should use `<ion-input type="tel">`

Like the doc said here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input

Comment: You were 19 seconds faster than me in posting this answer :)

Comment: hi @Shinichi Kudo, thank you for your answer. I have already tried in <ion-input type="tel">, that also allowing me to dot, but i don't want dots in the input field

Comment: Yeah, I tested it on web, dots can be entered, this is weird.
Does it allow dots when you run it on device or emulator?
I can't see dots on ```input type tel``` keyboards, on mobile, so your problem should be solved when you will run it on device

Comment: hi i tested in mobile device, it allowing me to enter dots

Comment: when i use input type number its allowing only one dot. but when used input type tel its allowing to enter multiple dots

Comment: Could you try with a normal HTML ```<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" />``` ? On device

Comment: And how can you enter dots with a "telephone keyboard" ? I can't see any dots on my Android Keyboard or iOS keyboard for input type tel

Comment: if i use normal html, the styling will change as there are other form fields also there. And iam getting numerical key board with dot key aswell when used input type tel or number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227025/discussion-between-shaik-and-shinichi-kudo).